# NextJS API routes are missing from Vercel's build outputs when folder contains index.js/ts

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I'm using NextJS /api routes and deploying to Vercel.

It seems that wherever I have an `index.ts` file located within the `/api` folder structure, Vercel will replace the contents of its containing folder (including `/api` itself) with a single file. All of the sibling route files will be ignored.

Oddly enough, the folder that contains the index file will remain--but without contents.

Ex:

```
/api/index.ts
/api/mock1/index.ts
/api/mock1/mock1-endpoint.ts
/api/mock2/index.ts
/api/mock2/mock2-endpoint.ts
```

This will produce an output of:

```
/api // empty folder
λ api
```

---

- Note: you'll have to deploy this code to see the output in Vercel's dashboard

---

Reproducible code: https://github.com/angusryer/missing-lambdas-vercel-nextjs

Deployed example: https://missing-lambdas-vercel-nextjs.vercel.app/

###### The api routes *are* visible as seen in the 'source' tab of the production deployment:

[image: source files available]

###### But they are not available in the 'output' tab:

[image: no output files]

Does anyone know why this happens and ways to get around it?

---

### Update March 2023

I have an index file in some of my folders. These are the ones that fail to produce build outputs.

It appears that when using NextJS /api routes, the contents of any folder (including /api itself) that contains an index.js/ts file will simple be replaced by a single api route lambda with the file contents of the index.js/ts. None of the folders other files will produce any build output. Oddly enough, the folder that contains the index file will remain--but without contents.

Ex:

```
/api/companies/index.ts
/api/companies/another-endpoint.ts
```

This will produce a lambda function output of:

```
/api/companies
```

Reproducible code: https://github.com/angusryer/missing-lambdas-vercel-nextjs

Live deployment: https://missing-lambdas-vercel-nextjs.vercel.app/

https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/7045#discussion-3698186